# No risk free security?

Tags: portfolio-management, capm

Imagine market without a risk free security. How is security market line constructed? How is it interpreted?

Comment: No market has truly risk-free securities.  They only exist in perception and for modelling purposes.

Comment: Use 0 as the "risk-free" rate of return? I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the question.

Comment: One of Fischer Black's contributions was to show that if there is no risk free asset you should use in its stead the portfolio of risky securities with the least variance (the so called GMVP).